# Having issues connecting PC to home media/gaming setup

Tags: switching, hdmi, display

Huge wall of text incoming, so please bear with me!

I have a media/gaming home setup consisting of an HDMI switch ([this one](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B0049SCB2Y/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) which allows me to connect my various devices to my fairly recent Acer GF276 monitor. I have an Xbox One S, a Nintendo WiiU, a Scart-to-HDMI upscaler (for retro consoles) and finally my desktop PC all connected to the same Acer monitor through the HDMI switch.
Then, at the output of the HDMI switch, I have an HDMI audio extractor ([this one](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B06X92VTRG/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) so that I can hook up some stereo speakers instead of using the crappy built-in speakers of my monitor. Finally, the HDMI audio extractor's HDMI output goes to my Acer monitor, and a nice comfy couch just 2 metres away from the Acer monitor completes my home media/gaming setup.

My desktop PC has its own separate set of 2 monitors which are all sitting on a desk in a different corner of my room, about 3 metres away from my Acer monitor where my media/gaming setup is. I would like to use this 3rd Acer monitor for PC games that I can actually play with a controller so that I don't have to sit in front of the PC and can instead chill on the couch. So, I bought a 10 metres HDMI cable ([this one](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B075MW4GRG/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) that goes arround my couch along the walls of my room and into the HDMI switch in order to avoid having to lay a cable on the floor through the middle of the room just to reach the HDMI switch.

Now all seems nice and pretty and all of the devices work wonderfully together! ... except for the desktop PC! For some reason now, if I run the setup described above (HDMI switch > HDMI audio extractor > Acer monitor), I am unable to get an image or sound out of my monitor when I switch to my PC. Even weirder; if I instead run either the HDMI switch (Desktop PC > HDMI switch > Acer monitor) or the HDMI audio extractor (Desktop PC > HDMI audio extractor > Acer monitor) separately, it works... for some reason.

Initially, I thought that perhaps I would need an HDMI repeater at the end of the 10m HDMI cable because perhaps the signal was somehow getting weaker and weaker with all the intermediary devices that I use, so I bought one of those ([this one](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B009117JP8/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) just to be sure and... no changes at all. Still the same problem!

Now admittedly, I am by no means an all-mighty guru when it comes to these things (even though I'm a software engineer) so I thought I would ask the community if they have encountered a similar problem before. Do you think that some other device or a different HDMI cable will yield better results? Or is the problem elsewhere? I am sure that I'm missing a tiny detail somewhere but I don't know what exactly...

Anyway, sorry for the huge wall of text, thank you for any help on this matter!

PS: I am running a Nvidia GTX750 Ti Boost graphics card on my desktop PC.

Comment: This is not related to Electronic design at all. Should be closed.

Comment: My bad! Wasn't sure where to put this question exactly...

Comment: The repeater shouldn't be placed in the end, but in the middle. There is a quote that reflect this scenario, SiSo, Shit In, Shit Out.

Comment: So you're basically suggesting that, instead of having one long 10m cable, I could have 2x 5m cables with a repeater in-between?

Because, ironically, I had tried placing the repeater at different spots (f.ex. 10m cable > HDMI switch > repeater > HDMI audio extractor) but to no avail...

What I am using right now as a temporary solution is that I'm connecting the 10m cable to the HDMI passthrough port on the Xbox One S, however I would have to turn the Xbox on whenever I want to use this port.